# How to catch a Django "GET" event in template using jquery?

Tags: jquery, django, ajax

In my Django project, I have a pdf download button that generates a report. When I push the button I would like a modal showing that the report is being processed. When the pdf is downloaded, I would like the modal to hide automatically.

However, I am having some trouble with the last part. I know that Django sends a "GET" message in the backend, when the report is downloaded ("GET /download/140/...")

[image]

How can I "catch" the ("GET /download/140/...") event in my template?

**Code:**

```
<a href="{% url 'report-download' object.id %}" class="btn btn-grey" id="pdf-button"></a>
```

Show "processing" modal when download is initiated...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#pdf-button").on("click", function(){
    $('#myPDFModal').modal('show');
});
</script>
```

**Attempt**: Close "processing" modal when download is finished using Ajax...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).on('click', '#pdf-button', function(event)
{
    event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url: '{% url 'report-download' object.id %}',
        type: 'GET',
    }).done(function(result) {
        $('#myPDFModal').modal('hide');
    });
});
</script>
```

The above code seems to work at showing/hiding the modal at the right "GET" event, but the pdf is not downloaded..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add `download` and `target="_blank"` to your pdf link.

```html
<a 
    href="{% url 'report-download' object.id %}" 
    class="btn btn-grey" 
    id="pdf-button"
    download="SuggestedFilename.pdf"
    target="_blank"
></a>
```

This will allow the file to appear in downloads without messing up the page location (that's my understanding of what you're trying to accomplish).

Next, in the onclick handler remove `event.preventDefault()` - that will make the link work again. And the .ajax call is no longer needed. So what's left is just `.modal('hide')`:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).on('click', '#pdf-button', function(event) {
    $('#myPDFModal').modal('hide');
});
</script>
```

And on those GET messages - that's your server's log. There is no way (for security, amongst other reasons) to access it from the front end. You can only wait for a reply from the server if you initiated the request (that's what you were doing with the `.done(...)` part of the ajax call).

And if you insist on doing an "ajax-like" download, see this answer: [Download a file by jQuery.Ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9970672/723891)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Actually I just want to close the modal box when the download is finished. I dont care if its Ajax or Javascript. I tried your solution but the .modal('hide') is initiated imididiately after i push the download button. What I want is to initiate .modal('hide') when the download is finished.

Comment: I see, have you tried the example from the answer I've linked? (you should replace your `$.ajax(...)` with that `fetch(...).then(...)` and hide the modal in place of the `alert(...)`)